# Issue using Parcelable attributes inside Parcelable Classes

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a "survey" type application that needs to pass data between activities so that it can eventually be written to an Excel doc, so I need to pass instantiated classes that have different data types to new activities so that I can gather more data. However, I'm using @Parcelize and think that it's causing an issue where the hidden boilerplate code is bouncing back and forth between parcels. I hope there is a solution to this without removing @Parcelize as I'm new to Kotlin and app development, but if there isn't then that's okay too.

Here is the long infinite loop error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.raymondllc.testapp, PID: 5396
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
               Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                  at android.os.Parcel$ReadWriteHelper.writeString(Parcel.java:353)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeString(Parcel.java:675)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:1797)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1790)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=48KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=48KB
      Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 3584(1418KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(1572KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 28MB/34MB, paused 720us total 341.766ms
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 184569(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 31MB/37MB, paused 671us total 213.138ms
I/chatty: uid=10080(com.raymondllc.testapp) identical 3054 lines
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Facility.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:47)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.Building.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:55)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1697)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:838)
                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542)
                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:878)
                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:9599)
                  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4327)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1611)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
                  at com.raymondllc.testapp.MainActivity.nextButton(MainActivity.kt:25)
                    ... 11 more
```

I think it's bouncing back and forth between reads/writes in the "Unknown Source" which, when I click on in Android Studio, bounce between two different classes I've written. Here are the classes' definitions:

```
@Parcelize
class Facility(private var facID : String,
               private var buildings: Array<Building>) : Parcelable {
    ...


@Parcelize
class Building(private var bldgID: String = "",
               private var sections : Array<Section> = emptyArray(),
               private var facility: Facility? = null) : Parcelable {
    ...
```

Any help/suggestions is much appreciated!

**Edit 1:**
I've removed the @Parcelize in front of the classes and allowed Android Studio to auto-generate the boilerplate code, and now I can see the problem but don't know how to go about fixing it. The `writeToParcel` function in the Building class calls `writeParcelable(facility, flags)`, which calls the `writeToParcel` function in the Facility class, which calls `writeTypedArray(building, flags)`, which calls `writeToParcel`on each building in the given facility, in turn repeating the process listed until stopped. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to break the circular dependency.  One way is to store just the id of the facility or building instead of storing the entire object.  You could write a separate class just for storing a slimmed version of the object, then reconstruct the original objects using the Ids.